# Opening a file in Vim opens vim diff?

Tags: git, vim, buffer, git-diff

When I open a file in vim, lets call it 'file1.rb', this file opens normally with ruby syntax highlighting and no problems up to this point.

When I open 'file2.rb' in a new buffer, it turns both of the buffers into `vim diff`.

I can switch buffers back and forth but what I'll see is a vim diff of the file open in each buffer. When I delete one of the buffers, I can use vim normally again without the vim diff color highlighting in the way.

At the moment I have only one buffer open at a time so that I don't run into this problem but I would like to have both of these buffers open at the same time with out it showing `vim diff` of the files.

Where can I disable this odd behavior, or any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Could you post your `.vimrc`? Also, just so you know, you can use the `diffoff` command to fix this, although I agree it would be better if you never needed to.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem please post this as an answer so that I can mark it. Thank you so much, the `diffoff` worked. To enable it again, all I have to do is `diffthis`. I can post my .vimrc if you would still like to see it.

Comment: Sure, I can post that as an answer, but it's really more of a band-aid than a solution. If vim automatically opens up in diff mode, then something is wrong (most likely something with your `.vimrc`)

Comment: You do have a point. I personally cannot find anything that causes this to happen right now but I'm glad there is an option to turn it off. Here is my '.vimrc': [https://github.com/csebryam/vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc](https://github.com/csebryam/vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim has a builtin command to disable diff mode, `diffoff`. From `:help diffoff`:

```
                            *:diffo* *:diffoff*
:diffo[ff]  Switch off diff mode for the current window.  Resets related
        options also when 'diff' was not set.
```

If you just want a quick fix, you can do this whenever you open a split, or even make a mapping or autocmd to make it easier. Perhaps something like

```
autocmd BufNew * diffoff
```

But this is definitely not the ideal fix.

There's still the issue of what causes it. A quick glance through your `.vimrc` shows *lots* of plugins, but I don't see anything in particular that would cause it. I'm 90% sure the issue is from one of the plugins, so I would start there as you're looking for the problem. Also, this post over on the dedicated vim site will help you a lot:

- https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/2920

Answer (score 2):

Diff mode is enabled either by one of the `:diffthis` or `:diffsplit` commands, or directly by `:setlocal diff`.

For the latter case, a `:verbose setlocal diff?` might tell you where it got set (when executed in one of the affected windows).

For the former, you can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands; i.e. search for 'diff'.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get the `diff` display when opening additional documents in vim. Happens only when I'm working in a large repo and still haven't figured out why that is. Regardless, having to go through and `:diffoff` each of my buffers is an irritant that I don't have to suffer. I wrote the following short mapping to allow me to turn it off for all my buffers (my `Leader` is the comma):

`nnoremap <Leader>,ndf :windo :diffoff<CR>`

So... a quick `,,ndf` sets `diffoff` in all my buffers in one shot.